# Retrieve Contacts from Salesforce & Show on Website

Tags: html, sql, joomla, export, salesforce

Maybe not a straightforward answer to this... but here goes.

All I want to do is retrieve and show a list of contacts contained in Salesforce on my website (the website runs on Joomla, but I just require the basic html code).

Please bare in mind I am a relatively newbie with Salesforce!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following options:

1. Create a public force.com site (setup-->develop-->sites). That is basically a visualforce page which can be accessed via a public url. So if you create a simple visualforce page to display your contacts as you like, you can IFRAME (or JS) embed it on your website.
2. Use the salesforce data api (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm) to extract your contacts from your website's backend environment.

From how you phrase your question, I'd suggest you start looking into alternative 1.

Comment: There are probably the two best options, a third would be to use the force.com API to extract the information, though your site would have to make a login call to salesforce also.

Comment: That was what I attempted to express as alternative 2 :) - I don't a third option?

Comment: What the? I must have read something else in my head! I think I thought you were suggesting to extract them in a one-off fashion using data loader :)